# Android ExoPlayer - video colors are messed up when using surface_type=surface_view

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Up until now I was using the player with surface_type=texture_view, however on slower devices the videos lagged.
I noticed that switching to surface_view improves the performance significantly, however I faced another problem.

On some devices the colors are somehow messed up - they appear a lot more red-ish and just not that vivid.
I tested on two devices, both API version 26 - one of them displays them fine, the other one is messed up.

And also I now get some flickering of the video - black screen appears for ~100ms a few seconds after the beginning.

I tried 2 exoplayer versions - 2.12.1 and 2.7.3 - no difference.
I tried 2 videos - mp4/x264 and webm/vp9 - again no difference.

Is there anything I can do to fix that, besides using texture_view?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding an Issue into the office ExoPlayer repository? Its developers will give you a faster answer, solution, or set it as a bug to fix. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues

Comment: @PerracoLabs, I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: any updates on the flickering issue with surface_view?

Comment: @Amr unfortunately I don't know what happened here - at some point I just stopped seeing this flickering and I don't think I did anything in the code or in the video encoding. Could be that my device was upgraded to a later Android.